# Using a R dataframe as a python dictionary

Tags: r

I am cleaning a huge dataset and need to replace some values for others. I have a data frame where each row has the value that I find in my dataset and the new value that I want to replace instead of it.

I am using gsub() and a for loop.

```
codes <- data.frame(Code = c("LL","DD","JJ"), Extended = 
c("LOL","DAD","John"))
df  <- data.frame(Supossed_Extended = c("LL","DD","JJ"), Values = c(1,2,3))

for (i in 1:nrow(codes){
    new = gsub(codes$Code[i],codes$Extended[i],df)
}
```

Result is not creating a dataframe or a list instead of it just let values stored.

The expected result would be a dataframe where the Supossed_Extended column has been changed by the Extended column in the codes file when the Code column and the Supossed_extended values match . That looks like this

```
new <- data.frame(Supossed_extended = c("LOL","DAD","John"), Values = c(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of `gsub` back to the dataframe. The following will work.

```
df$Supossed_Extended <- as.character(df$Supossed_Extended)
for (i in 1:nrow(codes)){
  new <- gsub(codes$Code[i], codes$Extended[i], df$Supossed_Extended)
  df$Supossed_Extended <- new
}
df
#  Supossed_Extended Values
#1               LOL      1
#2               DAD      2
#3              John      3
```